# Recursive calculations in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion

I have encountered an interesting problem.
There is the table with one column A.

I want to calculate each row of new column B by the formula B[i] = A[i-1] - B[i-1].

However, calculate this with SQL as "LAG(A - B) ... as B" is not possible because B is not yet defined.

Does anyone know how to solve it?
I have a huge table A, so we need something recursive here.

Comment: B must be defined or you could not reference it. So I assume B is null (no value assigned). You can try `lag(a) - coalesce(lag(b)),0)`

Comment: What is the value of B[0]?